# Какой род у слова ЮИД?

Tags: род

юные инспекторы дорожного движения

Answer (score 1):

Официальное название **ЮИД России**. Род здесь определяется по нарицательному слову, но они могут быть разными: проект, организация, движение, отряд.

Скорее всего, это **движение**, тогда можно сказать так: ЮИД было создано.

Но чаще эта аббревиатура используется вместе с родовым словом: отряд ЮИД был
создан, организация ЮИД была создана.